# Google charts annotation not showing

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I am using the google charts api to display data from php. I am displaying this information in a material style bar chart (vertical).

I am trying to add annotations to show the values inside the bars however it isn't working.

JavaScript:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLastPackets);

function drawLastPackets() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Days');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Packets Packed');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
    data.addRows(<?php echo json_encode($chartLastPackets); ?>);

    var toAdd = ["Day", "Packets Packed", {"role": "annotation"}];

    var options = {
        legend: {
            position: 'none',
        },
        series: {
            0: {color: '#d7a8a8'}
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Packets'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('lastPackets'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

The contents of the php array `$chartLastPackets` is:

```
[["Mon", 1, "1"], ["Tue", 3, "3"], ["Wed", 5, "5"], ["Thu", 2, "2"], ["Fri", 0, "0"]]
```

However all I can see is the chart itself without the annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`annotations.*` are listed among the [several options that don't work on *Material* charts](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

you can use the following option, to get the chart *close* to the look & feel of *Material*

`theme: 'material'`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Days');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Packets Packed');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
    data.addRows([["Mon", 1, "1"], ["Tue", 3, "3"], ["Wed", 5, "5"], ["Thu", 2, "2"], ["Fri", 0, "0"]]);

    var options = {
        legend: {
            position: 'none',
        },
        series: {
            0: {color: '#d7a8a8'}
        },
        theme: 'material',
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Packets'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('lastPackets'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="lastPackets"></div>
```